# Have I correctly set up these two volume of revolution problems questions?

Tags: calculus, volume

not sure if I am doing this right. I could really use some help if I am doing this. The two question ask to only set up the integral not integrate/evaluate.

Q1: R is the region between $f(x)= x^2$ and $g(x) = x+2$. Find the volume V1 of the region generated by revolving about the line $y = −3$

Q2: R is the region between $f(x) = x^2$, and $g(x) = 3x$, Find the volume V2 of the region generated by revolving about the line $y = − 2$

For the first:
$V = π\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{2} ( (x + 2 + 3)^{2} - (x^{2} + 3)^{2} )dx$

For the second:
$V = π\displaystyle\int_{0}^{3} ( (3x + 2)^{2} - (x^{2}+2)^{2} )dx$

Thanks!

Comment: Those look good.

Comment: @DougM Thanks! are you positive these are right?